# Как сохранять изображение по ссылке на Google диск на python pydrive?

Tags: python, парсер

Сначала парсю с сайта ссылку на изображение, это изображение сохраняю у себя локально, потом пытаюсь записать на гугл диск:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from io import BytesIO

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
def save_file_by_link(link):
    link_splitted = link.split('/')
    file_name = link_splitted[-1]
    print(file_name)

    try:
        drive = GoogleDrive(auth=gauth)

        response = requests.get(url=link)
    
        if response.status_code == 200:
            with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.content)

            my_file = drive.CreateFile({'title': file_name})
            with open(file_name, 'rb') as local_file:
                my_file.SetContentFile(local_file)
                my_file.Upload()
            print(f'File {file_name} was uploaded to Google Drive!')
        else:
            print("Failed to download the image.")
    except Exception as ex:
        return "Got some trouble"
```

Он ошибку никакую не выдает, но и ничего на гугл диск не сохраняет. Хотя локально на комп он сохраняется. Но также это сообщение print(f'File {file_name} was uploaded to Google Drive!') не выводится.
В чем у меня в коде проблема подскажите кто может?